# Error when writing to a TAG Mifare classic 1K

Tags: assembly, tags, mifare

Good morning all,
I develop in asm on PIC18 to drive a **PN7150**.
I perform reads / writes on a TAG **Mifare Classic 1K** using the *Mifare protocol*.
Authentication is going well as are reads from all sectors.
But during a write, the write request on a block returns Ok but after the data transfer I have a $10 $B2 notification.
What is this error? Thank you

**I use the procedure indicated in MCUXpresso IDE**
NXPNCI ...

PCD_Mifare_scenario

Auth   : $40 Bloc/4 Key    Ok

Read   : $10 $30 Bloc      Ok

Write1 : $10 $A0 Bloc      Ok

Write2 : $10 DATA          return $10 $B2

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is from the **NCI indicating** in :

RF Interface Specific Status Codes that the error **$B2 means RF_TIMEOUT_ERROR.**

Maybe someone can confirm this information for me.

Otherwise, as soon as I have performed the tests, I pass on this post.

Voilà !